# Cache-Control headers, max-age defined but back button always deliver web cache data

Tags: google-chrome, caching, nginx, cache-control

Im testing how `cache-control` header works on Chrome. 
My setup in `nginx` is quite easy:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    etag        on;
    root        /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
        add_header Cache-Control "must-revalidate, private, max-age=10";
    } 
}
```

The behaviour I was expecting for the setup would be:

- max-age: Use cache for the specified time in seconds
- etag: Use for validating freshness of data
- private: avoid proxy caches to keep the data

With hard-reloads Im getting the expected behaviour:

1- **First download hit the server and returns data with 200**

[image]

2- **Second refresh(ctrl + R) hit the server for validating freshness returning 304 if not modified or 200 if data was modified. (It seems that it's never served from web cache. Why?)**

[image]

The previous behaviour are mostly expected but **using `back` and `forward` button always retrieved data from web cache**. Why is this? Why if I modified data but use the `back`/`forward` button Im still getting stale data from cache? Even if I wait more than 10 seconds the result is the same. Just hard-reload will get new data.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caching headers work following way:

If **max-age** or **Expires** is set, then resource will be cached for provided time with one exception, if **Cache-Control** contains **must-revalidate** then following will happen.

> Because a cache MAY be configured to ignore a server's specified expiration time, and because a client request MAY include a max- stale directive (which has a similar effect), the protocol also includes a mechanism for the origin server to require revalidation of a cache entry on any subsequent use. When the must-revalidate directive is present in a response received by a cache, that cache MUST NOT use the entry after it becomes stale to respond to a
>   subsequent request without first revalidating it with the origin server.

or if **Cache-Control** contains **no-cache** then following will happen.

> If the no-cache directive does not specify a field-name, then a cache MUST NOT use the response to satisfy a subsequent request without successful revalidation with the origin server.

In addition you can combine **ETag** and **max-age/Expires** headers to make caching more qualitative. When time expires, browser will send **ETag** based revalidation request.

Note that **max-age** and **Expires** are equivalent, but **max-age** has higher priority.

One more thing, if you didn't provide any of previous headers, then browser (Chrome for example) can cache your resource for 10% of a time passed since **Last-Modified** header value, but any way will send revalidation request based on **Last-Modified** value of cached resource.

Comment: In the pic you can see than i'm using max-age. Still the behavior is the shown one. Max-age seems to not have any effect to serve file from cache. Am I missing some cschr-control setup in those requests or responses?

Comment: You have ETag, it takes all the blame for sending conditional request.
Can you please elaborate, what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Can you use cache-control: max-age combined with etag? Does this makes any sense? I thought that it would serve files from cache from 10 sec (based on max-age) and when not requesting files from more than 10 seconds it would do the conditional request to check the freshness of the resource/file.

Comment: @kitimenpolku: I've modified my answer, hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Look at this google fonts issue: https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/367 Expires [now] seems to superseed Cache-Control max-age=86400