# Leverage browser caching not working and resources duplicating

Tags: .htaccess, caching, laravel-5

I am having problems with my leverage browser caching. It seems that my resources are not fetched from cache and as you can see on the image below some of them are duplicating. I have these meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="private, max-age=216000">
```

Also I got this on my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# Set the cache-control max-age
<FilesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, public"
</FilesMatch>
# 2 DAYS
<FilesMatch ".(xml|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
# 4 HOURS
<FilesMatch ".(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=14400, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

# Turn off the ETags
Header unset ETag
FileETag None

# Turn off the Last Modified header except for html docs
<FilesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
Header unset Last-Modified
</FilesMatch>
```

[image: Chrome Network Tab output]

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Which problem you are trying to solve here, resource duplication or resource caching? If resource duplication, then provide source code, if caching problem then show us response headers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to resolve the caching. It seems that my resources aren't cache. I have added above the response headers and i've also changed the rules on my .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as I see from your screenshot, you haven't set any caching headers. Even though you said that you did, I can't see them on screenshot.

Here is an explanation of how caching headers work if you need it, just in case: [Cache-Control headers, max-age defined but back button always deliver web cache data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020837/cache-control-headers-max-age-defined-but-back-button-always-deliver-web-cache/36022760#36022760)

To make caching more efficient, you can load common libraries from public CDNs. For example you can load JQuery from their official CDN: look [here](https://code.jquery.com/)

Comment: I don't know what happened but it started caching already on the first load of the page, but when I refresh the page (on Google Chrome and localhost), the resources are not fetched from the cache but from the server.

Also, when I use Google's PageSpeed Insight, it says that I still need to configure my leverage caching for my resources.

Comment: If you press reload button in Chrome, than it reloads resources from origin. Try to navigate there from another page, or focus address bar and press enter. PageSpeed Insight probably asks you for Expires header to be set, but as far as I know, max-age is equivalent.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. I'll get back to this I'm still resolving it now.